# EFCore Database First Scaffold Error

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am trying to turn an existing PostgreSQL database into entities with Entity Framework Core 2.0.1 but I am getting an error when scaffolding.The database was created by running the following script:
[Script To Create Database](https://github.com/ODM2/ODM2/blob/master/src/blank_schema_scripts/postgresql/ODM2_for_PostgreSQL.sql)

I then run the following command in VS2017:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Host=localhost;Database=xxxx;Username=xxxx;Password=xxx" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

The operation runs fine for a little bit (there are some warnings, see below), but it fails with the following error message:

```
System.ArgumentException: The collection argument 'propertyNames' must contain at least one element.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty[T](IReadOnlyList`1 value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder.HasIndex(String[] propertyNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitIndex(EntityTypeBuilder builder, DatabaseIndex index)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitIndexes(EntityTypeBuilder builder, ICollection`1 indexes)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitTable(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DatabaseTable table)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitTables(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, ICollection`1 tables)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitDatabaseModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DatabaseModel databaseModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.CreateFromDatabaseModel(DatabaseModel databaseModel, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ModelScaffolder.Generate(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, String projectPath, String outputPath, String rootNamespace, String contextName, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The collection argument 'propertyNames' must contain at least one element.
```

Anybody know what the issue is here?

I am also getting the following two types of warnings. This is secondary, but I'd also appreciate help with understanding and resolving them.

```
Sequence with datatype integer which isn't the expected bigint.
Sequence with datatype integer which isn't the expected bigint.
Sequence with datatype integer which isn't the expected bigint.
The column 'tiger.street_type_lookup.is_hw' would normally be mapped to a non-nullable bool property, but it has a default constraint. Such a column is mapped to a nullable bool property to allow a difference between setting the property to false and invoking the default constraint. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851278 for details.
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any indexes with expressions as parameters?
Something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_index ON name_table (any incorrect expression)?
```

The expression can be inserted as corrupted in the pg_indexes table.

You can check via

```
select *
from pg_indexes
where tablename not like 'pg%'
order by tablename;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

About the sequence warnings maybe there is mismatch between the sequence return type and the primary key column Id. You can use BIGSERIAL which is BIGINT + autoincrement and in this way you can avoid the sequence hand typing. As foreing key column type use BIGINT.

About the is_hw column it has a constraint which may result in nullable value, on the other side the same column maybe is setted to NOT NULL.

Will this help you https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/892 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this post is still active or not; however, I was having this same error when using Entity Framework and it turned out my sql account need additional access to the DB.  I gave it db.owner access since this was just a local test project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error is exactly as [@tim-potter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61085/tim-potter) answered that this is a wrong usage of index, which results in runtime as `System.ArgumentException: The collection argument 'propertyNames' must contain at least one element.`

To fix this:
In the model classes, find this attribute `[Index(Name = "PropertyName", IsUnique = true/false)]`, when you do find that attribute, make sure the string `Name` instead of:

`Name = "PropertyName"` use `nameof(PropertyName)`

I think the reason for the `Name` property in Index Attribute not working is due to a bug in Entity Framework.